# MailMessage subject (with non-Ascii characters) not encoded when SMTP DeliveryFormat is International

Tags: encoding, smtpclient, mailmessage

When SMTP Delivery format is not set to International, it encodes the Subject line correctly.
Sample:

Subject: =?utf-8?B?QmVzdGVsbGVpbmdhbmdzYmVzdMOkdGlndW5nIEJlc3RlbGxl?=
=?utf-8?B?aW5nYW5nc2Jlc3TDpHRpZ3VuZw==?=

However, setting the DeliveryFormat to International ignores the encoding. and non-ascii characters are read as '?' or 'Ã¤'

We use 'International' to accept email addresses with accented characters.

Is there a workaround for this without having to encode the subject line manually?